# Template Page For Blazor Component

Tags: c#, layout, blazor

Basically I am trying to create a mix of a [Templated Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and a [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
I want a page layout that I can reuse, and still pass **required** parameters to. I think a way to do this may be to take advantage of an abstract base class.

This could be solved by my third option if I wanted to do it all through render tree building, but I do not want to do that. I'm okay with the base being built by a render tree (i.e. Option 3), but not the component that inherits from it (i.e. `MyGrid.razor`)

#### What I want to do:

`MyGrid.razor`

```
@page "/mygrid"
@inherits GridPage @*or "layout" or whatever works*@

<Grid>
    <Column>
    <Column>
</Grid>

@code {
    protected overrides string Title => "My Grid"
}
```

`GridPage.cs`

```
<header>@Title</header>
<div>@ChildContent</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

### Solutions I Have Tried

1. Layout

`GridLayout`

```
<header>@Title</header>
<div>@Body</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

*Issue* is that you have to remember this param is available and it is not required to impliment

2. Template

```
<GridPageTemplate Title="My Title">
    <Grid>
         <Column>
         <Column>
    </Grid>
</GridPageTemplate>
```

*Issue* here is that I would have to wrap my component with the template (not that big of deal, but would rather inherit) and I still don't know which params are required to impliment.

3. Abstract Base Class

```
public abstract class GridPage : ComponentBase
{
    protected abstract string Title { get; }
  
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenRegion(0);
        builder.OpenElement(1, "header");
        builder.AddContent(2, Title);
        builder.CloseElement();
        builder.CloseRegion();

        builder.OpenElement(3, "div")
        builder.OpenRegion(10);
        this.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        builder.CloseRegion();
        builder.Closelement()
    }
}
```

*Issue* is this one doesn't seem to work. I actually thought it would cause it would just take in the component and continue the base render (`this.BuildRenderTree(builder);`).

### Desired Outcome

Say you have two grids.. a `Students` grid and `Classes` grid. I would want a different grid (and title) for each of them. I want to customize the title and columns for each basically. They would have a common layout markup (what I call `GridPage`), but `MyGrid` (either `Students` or `Classes`) would be different.

`Students.razor`

```
@page "/students"
@inherits GridPage

<Grid RowType=Student>
    <Column For="StudentName">
    <Column For="StudentAge">
    <Column For="StudentHomeRoom">
</Grid>

@code {
    protected overrides string Title => "Students"
}
```

`Classes.razor`

```
@page "/classes"
@inherits GridPage

<Grid RowType=Class>
    <Column For="ClassName">
    <Column For="ClassTime">
</Grid>

@code {
    protected overrides string Title => "Classes"
}
```

They would both output

```
<header>Title_here</header>
<div>Grid_markup_here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the abstract base class with common properties required for logic and then extend it where you actually have to render.

AbstractBaseClass.razor.cs

```
public class AbstractBaseClass<T> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [Parameter]
    public T TypedObject {get;set;}

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<T> TypedComponent {get;set;}
    
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment CommonUi {get;set;}

}
```

In one implementation:

IntType.razor

```
@inherits AbstractBaseClass<int>
@CommonUi
 // or any other markup logic if any    
@TypedComponent(TypedObject)
```

StringType.razor

```
@inherits AbstractBaseClass<string>
@CommonUi
 // or any other markup logic if any    
@TypedComponent(TypedObject)
```

Then use it with the hard implementation

```
<StringType TypedObject="StackOverflow" >
  <CommonUi> /* Component common to both*/ </CommonUi>
</StringType>

<IntType TypedObject="2" >
   <CommonUi> /* Component common to both*/ </CommonUi>
</IntType>
```

Update: If you want to completely eschew the templated part, it is straightforward:

CommonLayout.razor

```
<div>
 <header>@Title</header>
 @ChildContent
</div>

@code
{
  [Parameter]
  public string Title {get;set;}
  
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent {get;set;}
}
```

Student.razor

```
<CommonLayout Title="Student Title">
  <Grid RowType=Student>
     <Column For="StudentName">
     <Column For="StudentAge">
     <Column For="StudentHomeRoom">
  </Grid>
</CommonLayout>
```

ClassRender.razor

```
<CommonLayout Title="Class Title">
  <Grid RowType=Class>
     <Column For="ClassName">
     <Column For="ClassTime">
 </Grid>
</CommonLayout>
```

Comment: Interesting idea @MayurEkbote , but it seems like a similar (and a more complicated) template solution?   

Would I just pass in a Page as `TypedObject`?

Comment: As RederFragment parameter? Yes. But I thought you were also looking for a common layout for both components. i.e. some components which are common to both and some specific. In IntType and StringType you can put your common ui elements by including a RenderFragment in the base class. Edited the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Could you impliment according to any of the generic examples I gave above? I think I follow you example, but I'm guessing I don't need the generic class/render fragement

Comment: See, the abstract class provides a placeholder for the common render elements (the header in your case). The generic members provide a way for the uncommon elements (the student and class part). All this because we want  to have a single component in the end. Otherwise, it is very straightforward.  Updated the example to show a simpler way.

Comment: Well that is a templated component you have done. As mentioned in the question, I do not prefer this way because of lack of requiredness and it doesn't feel right to do it this way as much

Comment: If you want to just enforce the usage of parameters, use [EditorRequired] attribute (available in .net 6).

Answer (score -1):

Component inheritance works for inheriting functionality, but not for content.  Here's the code snippet from `ComponentBase` that defines the `RenderFragment` delegate passed to the Renderer:

```
        public ComponentBase()
        {
            _renderFragment = builder =>
            {
                _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                _hasNeverRendered = false;
                BuildRenderTree(builder);
            };
        }
```

It calls `BuildRenderTree` i.e. the one in the child, which (as soon as you have some Razor content) overrides `BuildRenderTree` in the parent.

You need to think **Components**.

`GridPage.razor` is a component and looks like this:

```
<header>@Title</header>
<div>@ChildContent</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = "Silly sod, you didn't define a header";
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

and then `MyGrid.Razor` is a RouteView.

```
@page "/MyGrid"
<GridPage Title="My Grid Page">
    <Column>
    <Column>
... more markup
</GridPage>
```

Comment: This is the templated component route. I don't love the wrapping and how it does not have the params as required

Comment: If you want to build a base component with the functionality you want then you need to write your own base component.  Showing you how to do that is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.